# Android WebView when Wifi off

Tags: android

I have a WebView on my activity and I'm simply setting his url in code from assets like this:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + requestedHtmlPath);
```

all works fine when the wifi is on, but when it's off.. nothing happens..

The question is: Is the Wifi on is must for the WebView to work with a local html file?

Comment: what is the value of uri here?

Comment: Not neccessary if your accessing a local file or internal files. Share the Uri.

Comment: there should be no issue for wifi ... please check other issues.. also check logcat if there is any error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070247/streaming-to-videoview-only-plays-on-wifi-when-using-samsung-phones check this..

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. the issue is on WebView and not VideoView.. see my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is that there is no issue with WebView when Wifi is off, the thing is that I had in my html file an include to a js file on the web and when the Wifi was off obviously...

Thanks!